# Why doesn't this Kotlin program end?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Can anyone tell me why this program doesn't finish if you run it?

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(dispatcher)
    scope.launch {  }
    scope.cancel()
}
```

I was writing a bit of database code that I wanted to dedicate a thread to and noticed this behavior. If I just use `Dispatchers.IO` instead of making my own then it finishes right away, but I wanted a dedicated single thread in this case.

Comment: This is a trick question, right? You want us to solve the halting problem for you! ;-)

Comment: I would guess it's because `newSingleThreadExecutor()` returns an `ExecutorService` that uses a _non-daemon_ thread. Non-daemon threads keep the JVM alive. You probably have to either create the thread pool with a custom `ThreadFactory` that returns _daemon_ threads or somehow "dispose" the dispatcher when done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like @Slaw was right, it has to be manually closed. I guess its a somewhat arbitrary design choice?

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(dispatcher)
    scope.launch {  }
    scope.cancel()
    dispatcher.close() // missing  this
}
```

A bit unfortunate since the obsolete `newSingleThreadContext()` didn't require this.

Comment: If you look at the JVM source of [`newSingleThreadContext()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-single-thread-context.html), you'll see it [uses daemon threads](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/d88a8c227a295f91251960c8fe6b21a02ddf704b/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/ThreadPoolDispatcher.kt#L67). That's why explicitly closing the dispatcher was not strictly necessary, though the documentation does say that the dispatcher "_should be closed at the end of its lifecycle_".