# How to completely execute async method even after main thread execution ends?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a requirement in Kotlin where I need some logic in a method which includes logging and a network call.

I have tried different coroutine builders and async {} but no luck and I can not use threads. There will be thousands of requests.

This logic has high latency than the main flow itself. I want to execute this method asynchronously. But problem is

- Even the execution is async the main thread waits for it to complete
  before returning the response.
- If I use GlobalScope, the logging does not happen (I do not see the logs and I am not sure why this happens).

```
@GRpcService
class myApi() {

   override suspend fun createSomething(request: Request): Response  = coroutineScope {
       
        getSomething()
        getSomethingSomething()
        
        // I want to call a method here asynchronously 

        return response // but this response should not be delayed in any way
    }
}
```

Comment: Have yo tried running you async call in a dispatcher based over a *non-daemon* thread ? It should allow you to run your task in the background, but still prevent it to be cancelled before VM stops. See [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73453059/2678097) for this (in fact, the problem is the direct opposite of yours, but it show how to create / use a dispatcher on non-dameon thread).

Comment: Another problem might arise though. If you submit a lot of tasks on a dedicated non-daemon thread, and the wait-list grows, on JVM shutdown, the list of waiting tasks might be evicted, even if currently running tasks are completed before shutdown. As such thread/dispatcher requires an explicit close management code, you'd have to check remaining tasks yourself.

Comment: I tried different dispatchers, task gets started on worker thread in background but the main thread waits and does not return response until the coroutine executes completely. Will read the thread you added.

Comment: What do you mean by: "If I use GlobalScope, the logging does not happen"? Do you expect the server shutdown should wait for already scheduled asynchronous tasks?

Comment: Not sure why, I don't see logs on splunk from the code running in GlobalScope that's why I mentioned it vaguely logging does not work. 

Do you expect the server shutdown should wait for already scheduled asynchronous tasks - Yes and Response should be sent immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to fire off asynchronous work that doesn’t have to be waited for in the current coroutine, but must be finished before the app terminates. I have not tried this, but maybe you can store your top level `runBlocking`’s scope and use it to run these side tasks.

```
private lateinit var topScope: CoroutineScope

fun main() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    topScope = this
    //. . .
}

fun submitRequiredAsyncTask(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.()->Unit
): Job {
    return topScope.launch(context) { 
        try { block() }
        catch(e: Exception) {
            if (e is CancellationException) throw e
            // logging
        }
    }
}
```

```
@GRpcService
class myApi() {

   override suspend fun createSomething(request: Request): Response  = 
       coroutineScope {
   
           getSomething()
           getSomethingSomething()

           submitRequiredAsyncTask(Dispatchers.IO) {
               // I want to call a method here asynchronously 

           }
           response // but this response should not be delayed in any way
       }
   }

}
```

What we are doing here is running these tasks in child coroutines of the top level `runBlocking`, which must wait for all its children to finish. You were trying to run them either as children of the current coroutine (causing the hang as the current coroutine waits for its children) or as GlobalScope coroutines (the main function won’t wait for them to finish).

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea but I am not sure if it will work as I have not tested it but you can use [NonCancellable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-non-cancellable/) context. Here is example:

```
 @GRpcService
 class myApi() {

   override suspend fun createSomething(request: Request): Response  = 
    coroutineScope {
   
    getSomething()
    getSomethingSomething()

    launch(NonCancellable + Dispatchers.IO) {
       // I want to call a method here asynchronously 

     }
    return response // but this response should not be delayed in any way
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that the [documentation for `NonCancellable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-non-cancellable/) has a warning that, among other things, states "the whole parent-child relation between parent and child is severed" if you use `launch`. However, in this case you probably want that, so it might indeed work.

Comment: Yes that is true it breaks the structured concurrency but it is kind of wanted behaviour. Perhaps he can use withContext(NonCancellable) instead of launch.